# How is the value of path column under wagtailcore_page table is populated. How is it decided which page will have what value?

Tags: django, wagtail

I need to insert bulk pages in wagtail database and I need to find out how is the value of **path** column under **wagtailcore_page** table is decided?

I tried looking into the database but couldn't map the value of this **path** column to the path of the page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wagtail uses the [Materialised path implementation from django-treebeard](https://django-treebeard.readthedocs.io/en/latest/mp_tree.html) to represent the tree structure. The `path` string is a sequence of four-character elements - for example, "000000020001" can be read as "0000 0002 0001". For each level you go down the tree, you add a new element to that sequence - for example:

- 0000 is the root node
- 00000000 is the first child of the root
- 00000001 is the second child of the root
- 000000010000 is the first child of the second child of the root
- 000000010001 is the second child of the second child of the root

Each page's path always begins with the path of its parent, so you can quickly find all children and descendants of the page with path 00000001 by looking for paths starting with 00000001.

Also, note that these strings are not just numeric - django-treebeard uses an alphanumeric alphabet, so 0009 would be followed by 000A, 000B, 000C... and 000Z is followed by 0010. (This ensures that you can have a lot more than 9999 children per parent.)

Answer (score 0):

In Wagtail, the page column in the wagtailcore_page table corresponds to the Django model's Page instance and is used to store the hierarchical structure of the pages in the Wagtail CMS.

The page column represents the path or hierarchy of a page within the site. It is not stored as a direct path string but is encoded as a "materialized path." The materialized path is a way to represent the hierarchical relationship between pages in a database table. It typically uses a combination of numbers or strings separated by a delimiter to represent the nesting of pages.

In Wagtail, this materialized path is generated and maintained automatically by the system as you create and organize pages in the CMS. Each page has a parent page (except for the root page), and the materialized path of a page includes the IDs or slugs of its parent pages, separated by slashes.

For example, if you have a page hierarchy like this:

- Home

  - About Us

    - Team
  - Services

The materialized paths for these pages might look like this:

```
Home: /
About Us: /about-us/
Team: /about-us/team/
Services: /services/
```

Wagtail uses this materialized path to efficiently query and retrieve pages in their hierarchical order.

To insert bulk pages into the Wagtail database, you typically don't need to manually manage the page column. Instead, you can use Wagtail's API or Django's ORM to create and organize the pages programmatically. Wagtail will handle the assignment of the materialized path for you. You can create and organize pages in Python code using the Wagtail API, and Wagtail will take care of the details, including setting the correct page values.

Example of how you might create pages programmatically in Wagtail:

```
from wagtail.core.models import Page
from myapp.models import CustomPageModel  # Replace with your actual page model

# Create a parent page
home_page = Page.objects.get(slug='home')

# Create child pages under the parent
about_us_page = CustomPageModel(
    title='About Us',
    parent=home_page,
)
about_us_page.save()

team_page = CustomPageModel(
    title='Team',
    parent=about_us_page,
)
team_page.save()

services_page = CustomPageModel(
    title='Services',
    parent=home_page,
)
services_page.save()
```

In this example, you don't need to worry about manually specifying the page column value; Wagtail will handle it based on the hierarchy you define in your code.